# Submitting file via PHP form gives "function.fopen Filename cannot be empty" warning

Tags: php, forms, filenames, fopen

So, I put a form on a client's web site, and he's asking me to modify it so that people can attach a photo or two. So I'm running some tests, and whenever I submit the form, I get this error:

> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in
>   /homepages/20/d153810528/htdocs/fabFormHandlerTEST.php on line 32
>
> Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
>   /homepages/20/d153810528/htdocs/fabFormHandlerTEST.php on line 33
>
> Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
>   /homepages/20/d153810528/htdocs/fabFormHandlerTEST.php on line 100

Now, I'm guessing that for whatever reason, the file name is not being passed from the form. I'm not sending blanks, I'm actually clicking the "Browse" button and going right for a jpg.

First of all, here's the file input code from the HTML:

```
<td class="form">Picture #1 (optional)</td>
<td><input type="file" name="picture1" id="picture1" /></td>
```

When I click "Submit," the name should be sent to the form handler as "picture1", no?

Here's my PHP code to handle "picture1":

```
$file1name=$_FILES['picture1']['name'];
$file1type=$_FILES['picture1']['type'];
$file1size=$_FILES['picture1']['size'];
$file1temp=$_FILES['picture1']['tmp_name'];
```

And here are lines 32 and 33, where the trouble begins:

```
$fp1=fopen($file1name,"rb");
$file1=fread($fp1,$file1size);
```

I've tried replacing $file1name in the fopen() funciton with $file1temp, but that didn't make a difference.

I've confirmed that the server is set to allow fopen().

### What am I missing???

### EDIT

Here's the complete form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contactRich" id="contactRich" method="post" action="fabFormHandlerTEST.php" onsubmit="return fabFormValidate()">
<table cellpadding="6">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h3>Contact</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Your name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="cName" name="cName" size="31"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Neighborhood or closest major intersection:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cNeighborhood" size="31"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Your phone number:<br><span class="footer">(Include area code)</span></td>
        <td>(<input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" name="cAreaCode"/>) <input type="text" id="cNumber" name="cNumber" size="23" maxlength="8" onkeyup="addHyphen()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Your e-mail address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cEmail" size="31"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">What can we help you with?</td>
        <td><select name="cTopic">
                <option value="null">(Please choose:)</option>
                <option value="an estimate">Estimate</option>
                <option value="bifold doors">Bifold doors</option>
                <option value="broken window ropes">Broken window ropes</option>
                <option value="door that won't stay shut">My door won't stay shut!</option>
                <option value="noisy doors">My door is noisy!</option>
                <option value="sticking doors">My door is sticking!</option>
                <option value="drywall repairs">Drywall repairs</option>
                <option value="garbage disposals">Garbage disposals</option>
                <option value="grab bars">Grab bars</option>
                <option value="your various services">(other)</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Any additional details?</td>
        <td><textarea name="cAdditional" cols="27" rows="4" wrap="soft"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Picture #1 (optional)</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="picture1" id="picture1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Picture #2 (optional)</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="picture1" id="picture1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="form">Picture #3 (optional)</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="picture1" id="picture1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="isValid" name="isValid" value="no" />
</form>
```

Comment: `echo $_FILES['picture1']['name'];`, it's most likely empty.

Comment: please post your full form code , have set the enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: Here's the rest of the form, some styling etc. removed due to character count limitation:

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cont" id="cont" method="post" action="HandlerTEST.php">
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="cName" name="cName" size="31"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Phone:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="cNum" name="cNum"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>E-mail:</td><td><input type="text" name="cEmail"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pix:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="picture1" id="picture1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr></form>

Comment: `<input type="file" name="picture1" id="picture1" />` they **ALL** have the **same** name... don't do it. use different names. or use `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the value in `$file1name` is empty or NULL.  Back track the cause of the problem by temporarily adding `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: print_r($_FILES) doesn't give me any output at all.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is telling you that $file1name does not contain anything; check that you [set the correct enctype on the HTML form](http://php.net/upload) and go through the "Common Pitfalls" section.